# Twitter Bootstrap use hide instead of display:none

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap to develop a site and I'm issues with the tabs namely because they are using `display: none` instead of hiding the tabs. Its namely causing issues with iframes and position elements on hidden tabs.

My question is there a way to configure bootstrap to hide the tabs in a different way than the default implementation?

Comment: "*... instead of hiding the tabs..*," do you mind to explain?

Comment: find where bootstrap is setting `display:none;`, and set `visibility:hidden;` instead.  Your browser's web inspector should make it fairly easy to find where bootstrap is setting `display:none`.

Comment: Almost, except changing it to that and it never shows

Comment: Got it, it just takes a position absolute and problem solved.

Comment: @DevinDixon: you should write a complete answer, post it below, and then mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I would except it didn't quite solve the problem :/

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in the comments above, you have to use the visibility option. Also the position has to change because the div is taking up space and when you switch tabs, it will switch to a different location on the page. The end result of the css change looks like this:

```
.tab-content > .tab-pane,
.pill-content > .pill-pane {
  visibility:hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 930px;
}

.tab-content > .active,
.pill-content > .active {
  display: inline;
  visibility:visible;
   position: absolute;
   width: 930px;

}
```

Modify to your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I wanted to get the width of the element inside the tab.
I don't know if you want to do what you want to do when the tab is shown or not, but I guess this could help you when you click on tab and get elements feature:

```
$('#mytab a[href="#tab2"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
//the mytab is the id of your tab header and tab2 is 
the tab which is not active yet
});
```

hope this helps you